# Timeout awaiting response (Redis - ElasticCache - AWS)

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, redis, elastic-cache

I am receiving the following message from Redis when my system experiences a peak in transactions:

Timeout awaiting response (outbound=0KiB, inbound=0KiB, 5696ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=EVAL, next: EVAL, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 7, aw: True, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Writing, in: 11537, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: *...:6379, mgr: 9 of 10 available, PerfCounterHelperkeyHashSlot: 3957, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=39,Free=32728,Min=8,Max=32767), v: 2.0.601.3402.

This issue was happening before, but I migrated the structure to enabled cluster mode to try to solve it, and I'm still receiving this message.

Note: My application is built on .NET and uses the "AddStackExchangeRedisCache" command to configure the cache.

This issue was happening before, but I migrated the structure to enabled cluster mode to try to solve it, and I'm still receiving this message.